# gdalwarp -of GSBG not creating binary

Tags: gdal

Getting a rather annoying error message:

gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:3021 -t_srs EPSG:3006 -r near -of GSBG rg_DEM_1980.grd rgDEM_1980_tm.grd

Creating output file that is 389P x 243L.
ERROR 1: Golden Software ASCII Grid only supports Byte, Int16, Uint16, and Float32 datatypes.  Unable to create with type Float64.

The source file is binary, I am using the GSBG flag so to my mind ASCII grids not supporting Float64 seems rather irrelevant. Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Have tried setting the `-ot` and `-wt` to Byte?

Comment: Yeah, solved it now with -ot Float32. Didn't think I would need to specify not using a format it doesn't support. Should have tried that first before asking. Not sure how the file ended up being Float64 to begin with. Will have to check the sources more thoroughly. Sorry for needlessly posting

Comment: The error text has been fixed.  It sh ould have said binary. Thanks.